# Build Artifacts throwing bunch of errors IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors, compilation

build artifacts in IntelliJ have suddenly decided to throw a bunch of errors:
https://gyazo.com/618c068bd87973e0b04af91fea831c75

Looks like it is not finding anything, although it is building sometimes when I build as maven, then as artifact again. Then when I rebuild again it throws errors like this again. Has anyone experienced any similar issue to this? I have done some searching and have yet to find an answer, so I decided I would post here to see if any of you guys might know.

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'GKitPvP'
Information:javac 1.8.0_73 was used to compile java sources
Information:16/05/2017 8:31 PM - Compilation completed with 100 errors and 1 warning in 1s 725ms
C:\Users\Marius\Desktop\IntelliJ projects\GKitPvP\src\main\java\me\expdev\gkitpvp\GKitPvPPlugin.java
Error:(5, 1) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.commands does not exist
Error:(7, 29) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.gui does not exist
Error:(8, 35) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.listeners does not exist
Error:(9, 35) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.listeners does not exist
Error:(10, 31) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.tasks does not exist
Error:(11, 31) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.tasks does not exist
Error:(12, 31) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils does not exist
Error:(13, 37) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.other does not exist
Error:(14, 43) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.translation does not exist
Error:(15, 43) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.translation does not exist
Error:(39, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TextUtil
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(40, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Persist
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(66, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TextUtil
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(67, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Persist
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(88, 94) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SaveTask
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(93, 98) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AllowedTask
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(101, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable EnableUtil
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(121, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable GPlayers
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(122, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Points
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(123, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Spawn
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(124, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Kits
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(132, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Conf
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(140, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable GPlayers
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(141, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Points
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(142, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Spawn
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(144, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Conf
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(151, 47) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GKitPvPCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(152, 52) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GKitPvPStatsCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(153, 48) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SetSpawnCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(154, 45) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpawnCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(155, 48) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SetPointCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(156, 51) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RemovePointCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(158, 44) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class KitsCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(159, 45) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StatsCommand
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(176, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PlayerListener
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(177, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DamageListener
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(178, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PaneListener
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Warning:(217, 68) java: loadConfiguration(java.io.InputStream) in org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration has been deprecated
Error:(218, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TL
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(245, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TL
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(245, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TL
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
Error:(251, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TL
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.GKitPvPPlugin
C:\Users\Marius\Desktop\IntelliJ projects\GKitPvP\src\main\java\me\expdev\gkitpvp\persist\MemoryGPlayer.java
Error:(4, 29) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.gui does not exist
Error:(5, 29) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.gui does not exist
Error:(6, 43) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.translation does not exist
Error:(7, 43) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.utils.translation does not exist
Error:(8, 34) java: package me.expdev.gkitpvp.wrappers does not exist
Error:(26, 48) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class GPlayer
Error:(225, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class KillReward
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(251, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class KillReward
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(273, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TL
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(303, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Kit
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(328, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Kit
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(334, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GLocation
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(49, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(54, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(59, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(64, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(69, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(74, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(79, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(84, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(89, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(94, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(96, 58) java: package TL does not exist
Error:(101, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(106, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(111, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(116, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(121, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(126, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(131, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(136, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(141, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(146, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(151, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(159, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(169, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(174, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(179, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(189, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(200, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(202, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Conf
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(205, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(224, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(250, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(255, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TextUtil
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(267, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(272, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(277, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(295, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(302, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(327, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(333, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(344, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(346, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GLocation
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(346, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Points
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(355, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(358, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GLocation
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
Error:(358, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Spawn
  location: class me.expdev.gkitpvp.persist.MemoryGPlayer
C:\Users\Marius\Desktop\IntelliJ projects\GKitPvP\src\main\java\me\expdev\gkitpvp\featherboard\PlaceholderHook.java
Error:(9, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GPlayers
  location: package me.expdev.gkitpvp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've just got plain old errors. Fix them if you do. If not, try going to

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

IntelliJ might get a bit confused under certain circumstances. Invalidating cache, basically making it re-check the full code for errors, etc.. might fix it.